# How did read an Ad delivery script the parameter?

Tags: javascript, php

I try to understand, how an Ad delivery script reads the given parameter:

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="4" data-revive-id="224492f55da08gg67b9eegh3006534r1"></ins>
<script async src="/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

This code is from the Revive Ad server.
I try to look into the asyncjs.php file - but I can't find out, how the script reads the parameter like **data-revive-zoneid** and **data-revive-id**.

Can someone explain me, how that works? I need to try to develop an similar solution for an new project idea.

Thanks.

Comment: So you look for the element and read the attributes

Comment: Thanks for answer ... I figured it out - based on @MrCode's answer ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `asyncjs.php` although named php, would output JavaScript, something that finds the element like:

```
var element = document.querySelector('ins[data-revive-id]');
console.log( element.getAttribute('data-revive-id') );
console.log( element.getAttribute('data-revive-zoneid') );
```

Comment: Yes, I found out, that an JS code will be included into the PHP file. There I found some code similar to yours. But looks much more complicated - I'm not familar with JS ...
But thanks for your feedback.